# An easy-to-manage self-hosted wiki

Tags: wiki

I want to start a wiki for group knowledge-sharing at work. I'm not a manager, so I can't set aside a special (virtual or actual) server; and on the server where I can run it - I might not even have root access. Also, it has to be flexible in the sense of not being picky about what's available on the system, and being easy to "pack up" and migrate to another machine as necessary with minimum hassle.

The wiki will likely not have incredibly fancy and complex programmed elements; also, I'm not experienced with Wiki systems as an admin - only as a user (and not even such a power user).

The wiki has to be FOSS, or at least gratis for both commercial and personal use. Also, it should (somewhat) actively maintained.

The material may include a bunch of text, some formal math, occasional tables, scans, diagrmas... perhaps a short video.

Notes:

- I'll be choosing and running the web server, so you can make assumptions about it if necessary.

Comment: Does the server you have access to have a web server installed?

Comment: @EricShain: See edit. It'll have whatever I install.

Comment: I’d check out https://www.wikimatrix.org/ Personally, I like DokuWiki.

Comment: @EricShain: There are over 80 wikis there! :-O

Comment: @EricShain: So, for now, I've narrowed it down to [these Wikis](https://www.wikimatrix.org/compare/dokuwiki+pmwiki+twiki+wiki-js+tiddlywiki+foswiki+gwiki+pepperminty-wiki+wala-wiki+hatta) using my criteria, and dropping ones that have not been updated over the past few years. I might narrow the maintenance criteria further...

Comment: DocuWiki is nice and it doesn’t require a database as it is file based.

Comment: @EricShain: So could you write up DokuWiki in an answer? Describe your experience with it maybe?

Comment: My experience was from quite a few years ago. I just installed several on my PC and tried them out. DokuWiki was easy to install and use, but your needs might be different than mine.

Comment: I am also using Dokuwiki. If you run Linux, you already have an Apache server; if Windows, install XAMPP. DokuWIki is established, stable, popular and well supported (plus, no database necessary). I used markup, but there is also a WYSIWYG plugin.

Answer (score 1):

We use [dokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki) since roughly ten years.

It has a lot of plugins.

There is a nice table-edit plugin: You can edit the content of each cell on its own. Editing a whole table as ascii-text is not nice.